# Why google chrome browser is not reflecting the changes in the code even after refreshing the browser?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, httpserver

I'm learning this [Angular JS tutorial](https://www.udemy.com/ultimate-angularjs-course/learn/v4/overview) from Udemy. I used `http-server` for running the application locally.

The issue here is - When I run my application using `http://localhost:8080` on **Google Chrome**, the changes that I make in the code are not reflecting on the browser right away. I need to close my browser and reopen or I need to open my application in Google chrome's incognito mode it's working fine.

May I know why this is happening? Is it because of Cache? Can anyone explain!

Comment: you need to press ctrl+F5 for refresh.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling Chrome cache for website development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to press ctrl+F5 for refresh.Ctrl-F5 forces a cache refresh, and will guarantee that if the content is changed, you will get the new content.